# Difference between averaging and taking n-th root of products

Tags: average

It seems like taking the n-th root of the product of n values is analogous to the traditional form of averaging. For example:

$$
\frac{5+5+5}{3} = 5 = \sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{0}3]{(5*5*5)}
$$

But they do not always produce the same results

$$
\frac{1+2+3}{3} = 2
$$
$$
\sqrt[\leftroot{0}\uproot{0}3]{(1*2*3)} = 1.817...
$$

Also, the n-th root "average" cannot handle negative numbers. Anyway, what are the benefits of this latter form of averaging versus the standard way?

(Context: I'm in a course where "[perplexity](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/Speech/docs/HTKBook3.2/node188_mn.html)" was intuitively defined as the "average amount of surprise". It made me wonder why we don't just use the standard way of averaging.)

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means (You are wondering about the relation between *arithmetic* and *geometric* means).

Comment: @clementc. I believe that the OP is asking for an application for which a geometric mean is appropriate and more meaningful in some sense than an arithmetic one.

Comment: The geometric mean is less sensitive for exceptional values. An extreme example : $$\frac{10+10+10+10+10^9}{5}=2\cdot 10^8+8$$ and $$(10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10^9)^{1/5}\approx398.1$$

Answer (score 0):

The geometric mean can be thought of as $e^y$ where $y$ is the average of the natural logarithms of your values.  That is $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^\frac 1 n = e^{ {\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i  \right)} \over n}$$Thus this sort of average is useful when your values can be thought of as powers of some base, and you want to find the average value of the exponent.